# Elasticseach - Range aggregation that only counts the very highest price of each product

Tags: elasticsearch, search, range, aggregation, cardinality

lets say we have a dataset with documents that have a productname and a price the product got sold with:

```
{
   "product": "Table",
   "price": 20
},
{
   "product": "Table",
   "price": 20
},
{
   "product": "Chair",
   "price": 20
},
{
   "product": "Table",
   "price": 70
}
```

Now, I want to get only the records of each product with the highest price and count them in a range aggregation.

This is what I did:

```
{
"aggs":{
  "PriceRange":{
    "range":{
      "field":"price",
      "ranges":[
        {"from":0.0,"to":24.0},
        {"from":25.0,"to":49.0},
        {"from":50.0,"to":74.0},
        {"from":75.0}
      ]
    },
    "aggs": {
      "Users":{
        "cardinality":{
          "field":"userid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

But with that query, the Table will be counted one time in the 0-24 bucket and the 50-74 bucket because the cardinality applies per bucket. But I just want to count the very highest price for each product.

I hope the issue is clear and you can help me :)

Greetings

Comment: To be clear you want the product with highest price and on top of it you want to apply ranges? So let's say if you have a table with price 30 and a table with price 70. You just consider the second table with price 70 so in that case you'll have distinct products having highest price?

Comment: yes, thats right. To archive this, i could do a term aggregation on the product and than make a max aggregation on the price. But then, the Range is missing